# How to generate a set of random variables with specific correlations and correlational distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, correlation-matrix

I apologize if this question is a bit confusing.

Suppose we get to generate an $n \times n$ matrix, $M$, whose values are all between 0 and 1.

How can we generate a set of $n$ random variables, $\{X_1...X_n\}$ whose correlational matrix, $M'$ ($M_{i,j}=corr(X_i,X_j)$), is proportional to those values found in $M$ ($M_{i,j} \propto M'_{i,j})$ , and whose values follow a normal distribution (other than the $corr(X_i,X_i) \forall i \in n$) with pre-specified mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ (i.e., $mean(\{M_{ij}:i,j\in n\}) = \mu$ and $var(\{M_{ij}:i,j\in n\}) = \sigma^2$?

What constraints would $M$ have to follow and how could these random variables be computed?

My goal is to seed certain values within $M$ in order to see if they're recoverable in $M'$.

Comment: This doesn't seem to directly be a random matrix question (there is a matrix in your question but it isn't full of random entries) or explicitly be about a time series, so I have removed those tags. But perhaps removing the time series tag was a bit zealous - feel free to add that back if you think it is relevant after all.